# retrieve json formatted data using xmlhttp request

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I was using jQuery and this was done easily but I want to change it to regular javascript because I will be using it with phonegap and I don't want to loop through js frameworks every time I make a request to the server.  Maybe it's a bad reason to go away from jQuery but seems like it would make everything faster.  So I need some help with this code:

```
<body onload="init();">
  <div id="daily"></div>

<script>
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200){
      var a = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
      document.getElementById('daily').innerHTML = a.items;
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", serviceURL +"getmainnews.php" , true);
  xmlhttp.send();
  }
</script>
```

getmainnews.php

```
//mysqli query
$daily = array();
while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($day)){
  $daily[] = $r;
}
echo json_encode(array("items" => $daily, "allitems" => $mainnews,...));
```

In the Chrome DT, I can see the encoded data which is returned but I can't display the first item into my first div with id="daily".  With the code I provided, all I get is [object, Object].  What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

So my query selects the entire row from my database and it's in an array:

{"items":[{"id":"1","pic":"","topic":"daily","article":"  \t\t\t\t\t  \t\t\t\t\t\u0417...","link":"http://www....","text_cont":..."}]}

How can I display just the pic and the article without all the other junk?  Do I have to modify my php file?

EDIT 2:

```
$day = mysql_query("SELECT pic, article, link FROM table WHERE topic='daily' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
$daily = array();
while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($day)){
$daily[] = $r;
}

$exc = mysql_query("SELECT pic, article, link FROM table WHERE topic='exclusive' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
$excl = array();
while ($e = mysql_fetch_assoc($exc)){
$excl[] = $e;
}

$mus = mysql_query("SELECT pic, article, link FROM table WHERE topic='must' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
$must = array();
while ($m = mysql_fetch_assoc($mus)){
$must[] = $m;
}
echo json_encode(array("items" => $daily, "exc" => $excl, "must" => $must));
```

That's my full php file with the queries.  Items, exc, and must are arrays, so the responseText, I guess, is a multidimensional array?  Is that the problem I'm having with displaying it?

EDIT 3:

console.log(a.items) gives me an "undefined"  so I logged the xmlhttp.responseText.

[image: Console Log]

Comment: You should do a console.log on xmlhttp.responseText and post what you are getting back.

Comment: In the console I get a whole bunch of data and it's encoded.  For example: {"items":[{"id":"1","pic":"<img src=\"http:\/\/basket-planet.com\/files\/news-main\/PHX.jpg\">","topic":"daily","article":"  \t\t\t\t\t  \t\t\t\t\t\u0417\u0434\u0440\u0430\u...

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing exactly what your JSON looks like it is hard to know for sure.  However since you are encoding an array, I suspect changing:

```
a.items
```

to

```
a[0].items
```

will do the trick...

**Edit**

I would do:

```
document.getElementById('daily').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(a.items);
```

That will convert your object into a string that can be assigned to the `innerHTML` of an element.  I am not sure if this is exactly what you want to do, but when you find the element you want to display using that method should work.

**Edit 2**

You could change your PHP to only output what you want.  However, you could filter it in your JS as well:

```
a.items[0].pic
```

and

```
a.items[0].article
```

If those don't display as is you can use the `stringify` method, but you shouldn't need to since those items appear to be strings.

Also note, if you have multiple items you will need to change the 0 to the index of the item you are targeting.

Comment: When I add the zero, it gives me an "undefined items".  Leaving it like it was gives me [object Object].  What information do you need to see to help me out some more?

Comment: @user2025469 Yeah that was a good hunch but not the right answer, I have an idea for you that I will add as an edit to my answer.

Comment: I'm going to edit my answer because now I'm getting the output of everything in that row...I need help displaying a certain part of the array first.  Don't give up on me! :)

Comment: Dammit...nothing works.  I tried all combinations and I get either undefined, cannot read property pic of undefined, or some other error.  I'm lost...

Comment: @marteljin I added my full PHP file...can you please look over how I'm sending the data back...maybe there's some problem there?

Comment: @user2025469 could you put `console.log(a.items);` in your callback, expand the array in ur console (chrome preferrably), take a screen shot and post it

Comment: Edited...hope I did that right, first time i posted a screenshot.  Hope it helps